# Calculate covariance matrix from x,y,z data of /odom

Tags: ros, kalman, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recorded a bag file from a custom robot (in real world) that does not provide covariane matrix and I want to use `/odom` to feed an `ekf`, but covariance matrix is 0. How can I calculate it?

It's a sample of `/odom`:

```
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.082
      y: 0.507
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.789272088731
      w: 0.614043622188
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.104
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0663225115758
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98316/calculate-covariance-matrix-from-x,y,z-data-of-/odom/) by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-15**:
which package you are using? Your question may help me in some points. I am also facing same problem. I want to use robot_localization package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use diagonal matrix for the covariance. each element in the diagonal entries is your best expectation about the odom variance.

---

Originally posted by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) with karma: 179 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-15**:
Anas, its very old question, and the person is not looking here from last june.

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2015-01-16**:
It is better late than never :)

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-16**:
Hmm.. Impressive.